# Direct Update not working in Worklight 6.1?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

I have what I think is a pretty typical Worklight Hypbrid application that had been working fine with Direct Update for months.  Recently I noticed the Direct Update stopped working and I can't seem to figure out why.  In my logs, I see that `WL.Client.connect(options)` completes successfully, but I see a the message `Empty direct update payload received. Skipping direct update.`  Any guidance one how to troubleshoot or resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I see in my logs:

```
[INFO] [wl.client] WL.Client.connect onConnectSuccess ENTERING
[DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient connect success
[DEBUG] [NONE] Empty direct update payload received. Skipping direct update.
```

Comment: What is your exact build number? I suggest that you will obtain that latest 6.1 iFix from IBM Fix Central (available for paying customers) that contains numerous Direct Update-related fixes.

Comment: Server version is: 6.1.0.01.20140311-2356

Comment: Studio version is: 6.1.0.01.20140518-1532

Comment: 1) download the latest version from Fix Central; 2) use the same Server and Studio versions.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest version from Fix Central and updated the Server and Studio and my ant build scripts.  Direct Update still is not working and is displaying the same messages in the log as above.  My Server, Studio, and build environments are now at `6.1.0.01.20140630-1541`.

Comment: Did you find a way to fix it? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations it appears that Direct Update failed because the .settings folder, that is part of the Worklight project, was missing from the source control system used.

This folder contains required data for Direct Update, used when the Ant task builds the application artifact (.wlapp file).